# How to show that $E[|Y_n|]<\infty$ in martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let $X_1,X_2,..$ are i.i.d. random variables with $E(|X_1|)<\infty$. Define the partial sum $S_n = X_1+X_2+...+X_n$.

Show that $Y_n=S_n-n \mu$ is a martingale where $E(X_1)=\mu$.

I took $\mathcal{F}_n= \sigma(X_1,..X_n)$, and I proved that $E(Y_{n+1}|\mathcal{F_n})=Y_n$ and $Y_n \in \mathcal{F_n}$.

Now, I want to show that $E(|Y_n|)<\infty$.

$E(|Y_n|)=E(|S_n - n \mu|)\leq E(|S_n|)+n \mu$.

How do I say the right hand side term of the above equation is finite?

Comment: $Y_n$ is a sum of elements in $L^1$, so it is in $L^1$ as well...

Comment: $0\le E\left[\left| S_n\right|\right] = E\left[\left|\sum\limits_1^n X_i\right|\right] \le E\left[\sum\limits_1^n\left| X_i\right|\right] =  \sum\limits_1^n E\left[\left| X_i\right|\right]$ which is finite since $n$ is finite and each $E\left[\left| X_i\right|\right]$ is finite

Comment: @Henry I understand it. I was confused because of the n on the right side. Thank you.